# Intel XDK geo location sample stuck at the first hurdle

Tags: android, geolocation, intel-xdk

I am trying to learn how to build Hybrid apps and am using Intel XDK.

So I installed the software, created a new project using the sample geo location template ( https://software.intel.com/en-us/html5/articles/intel-xdk-geolocation-sample ), tested it using app preview and it was fine so built it for Android.

However when I installed it and went to run it on my phone I got the following error after the splash screen...

"Error calling method on NPObject"

Afterwards I created another project using the same starter template, and this time built it for Crosswalk for Android,

Upon trying both the 86 and the ARM version I got no error, but the map failed to load leaving me with the title and white screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error that you are mentioning is linked to the *intel.xdk.geolocation.watchPosition(suc, fail, options)* method. The **"Error calling method on NPObject"** message happens when you try to use methods called from a JavaScript interface to interact with the UI on Android 4.3+.

I recommend that you use PhoneGap (*navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(suc, fail, options)*) instead to avoid this error. For more information on using the PhoneGap Geolocation API, visit http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.5.0/phonegap_geolocation_geolocation.md.html#geolocation.watchPosition

Comment: thank you , the other answer gave me a working app with all the features, but upon reading this and then looking back at the js in the working app, I noticed that even that app is using navigator.geolocation.watchPosition

Answer (score 0):

try this

1) access this link and download the project : https://github.com/gomobile/sample-html5-geolocation-map

2) Create a new project at the intel xdk, and the path the project at the paste WWW, remove the files js, css and the índex.html.

3) go the project that you do download at the paste WWW, copy and paste inche project that you create at intel xdk

4) Copy the others files outside the paste www, for the other project.

For me worked, I tested at my Android device.

I hope help you something.